# What does ‘-hupf’ mean in ‘der Googlehupf’?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, neologism, wordplay

The article *[Knusprige Zukunft](http://taz.de/Die-Wahrheit/!5331554/)* appears in the section of the *taz.de* called *die Wahrheit*. This section of the newspaper tells various fables. I’m quoting below the paragraph from the article where the word *der Googlehupf* appears:

> Schon sind weitere Internetriesen auf die geballte Backkompetenz der Deutschen aufmerksam geworden. Patisserie 4.0 heißt der Trend der Stunde: So arbeitet Google seit geraumer Zeit an einem geheimen Projekt mit dem Nahrungsmittel-Multi Dr. Oetker zusammen. **Der Googlehupf**, wie der leckere Kuchen heißen soll, vereint Insidern zufolge eine lockere Krume mit unübertroffener Nutzerfreundlichkeit. Ein in den Teigpartikeln integriertes Nano-Diagnosetool ist in der Lage, noch während des Kauvorgangs relevante Gesundheitsdaten des Nutzers zu erfassen und direkt an das Google-eigene ärztliche Betreuungszentrum zu übermitteln. Gesundheitschecks gehören nunmehr der Vergangenheit an, sie werden in Zukunft direkt beim Kuchenessen durchgeführt.

I could not find the word *der Hupf* in any of the dictionaries (dict.cc, Leo’s dictionary or any others).

Comment: BTW You can find "Hupf" in Duden. http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Hupf

Comment: @Alex.S Duden, however, informs us that "Der Hupf" means "der Sprung", or jump. I'm not sure I'd have been able to conclude from the Duden entry that "Der Hupf" can also refer to a cake.

Comment: Sure, "der Hupf" doesn't refer to a cake. An entry in dict.cc or Leo wouldn't refer to a cake either.

Comment: @EugeneStr. it's the small jump your heart makes when you found something during a web search. ;)

Comment: By the way, Google Zurich serves "Googlehupf" (a "Marmorguglhupf", i.e. a chocolatey and a white dough swirled together, but colored in Google colors using food colors) every now and then as a dessert in its main cantina.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is a play of words alluding to the cake known as [*Guglhupf*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gugelhupf) (also spelt *Gugelhupf*). This type of cake is well-known throughout the German-speaking regions even though the exact name may differ. Typically, it is defined by the shape, not the type of dough.

Its pronunciation is /gu:glhupf/ and the first two syllables resemble the German pronunciation of *Google* (/gu:gl/ or /gu:gəl/) strongly. I’m sure that there is a multitude of non-published puns of that type out there, and I can totally imagine people saying *Guglhupf* instead of *Google* in all occasions for comic effect. (I personally use *Goggel* for the same.)

Comments have informed me of the origin of *Hupf:* It derives from *Hefe* in some way. I’ll point to [Thorsten Dittmar’s answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/31692/15318) for the etymologic explanation. However, I would assume that the journalist responsible for writing the article didn’t know that either.

Probably needless to say but worth pointing out nonetheless that *die Wahrheit* from the *taz* is satiric.

Comment: DWDS identifies *-hupf* as a variant of *Hefe* (*yeast*).

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Right - *Hupf* == "Hefe", *Gugel* == "Kapuze, Kappe"

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar also, dann hätte ich Hupfgugel genommen, aber eine Möglichkeit ist es!

Answer (score 32):

### On the dessert *Gugelhupf*

The text is a play of words involving Google and the dessert Gugelhupf. As for the latter word it is supposed to come from merging *[Gugel](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gugel_(Kleidung)#/search)* and *[lüpfen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/luepfen)*. This could loosely be transated "hood lift". It refers to the process of making the dessert in a round form, from which it gets its distinctive shape. [Wiktionary](https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Gugelhupf#) interpretes Gugel slightly differently, but the essence remains:

> Die Bezeichnung „Gugelhupf“ kommt vermutlich von Lupfen des Gugels, also dem Hochheben des rundlichen (vergleiche Kugel, Kogel, Kogge) Napfes oder Kessels, nachdem der fertig gebackene Kuchen umgedreht wurde. Das „h“ in Gugelhupf beruht auf einer Übertragung aus dem Dialekt ins Hochdeutsche, deutet aber nicht auf „Hüpfen“. Im Dialekt wird das Wort noch heute etwa Gug'lupf ausgesprochen.

Note, that *lupfen* is a variant of *lüpfen* and listed as such in [the relevant Duden entry](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/lupfen).

Surprisingly, the [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Gugelhupf) indeed offers a different etymology and makes a connection to *hüpfen* on the basis of the elevated surface of the cake:

> 2. Bestandteil wohl zu hüpfen, wegen der sich nach oben hebenden Oberfläche.

Digging deeper, I traced this all the way to [Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GG31881#XGG31881):

> GUGELHUPF, auch gogelhopf, m., bezeichnung eines kuchens. nieder- und mitteldeutsch entsprechen topf-, napf-, asch- oder formkuchen. der zweite bestandteil dürfte zum verb. hüpfen gehören und bezieht sich auf die infolge der hefe sich wie eine gugel hebende obere fläche des kuchens. das wort ist vornehmlich oberdeutsch und reicht nur wenig in mitteldeutsche gebiete hinein, vgl. Follmann lothr. 318; Vilmar Kurhessen 139; Reinwald henneb. 2, 156; Martin-Lienhart elsäss. 1, 362; Fischer schwäb. 3, 735; Staub-Tobler 2, 1492; Schmeller-Fr. 1, 880; Loritza id. Vienn. 56. im schwäb. und bair. herrscht die form gogelhopf vor. zum ganzen vgl. Kretschmer wortgeogr. 352 f. vereinzelt bedeutet gugelhupf auch eine art gebackener nudeln: zu was für einen schleckerbiszl? villeicht hat ihn gelust nach einen bairischen gogelhopf? Abr. a s. Clara Judas 1, 275; da soll sie alleweil hinter dem ofen hocken wie ein bairischer goglhopf 228; an statt des brods kan man mandeln mit rosenwasser abstoszen, eier daran schlagen, zuckern, dann auf gugelhöpflein oder semmelschnitten

Other answers show etymologies that connect *Hupf* to *Hefe* (yeast). That is not a bad idea, since yeast is the basis for today's standard recipe. Yet, [Wikipedia](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gugelhupf#/search) claims that in olden times there was no standard recipe:

> Der Gugelhupf wurde in der Biedermeierzeit in Deutschland und Österreich im Bürgertum populär und galt geradezu als Statussymbol. Alte Kochbücher belegen, dass es lange Zeit kein Standardrezept für diesen Kuchen gab.„Je nach Region, festlichem Anlass und wirtschaftlichem Vermögen wurde der Gugelhupf aus Hefe-, Rühr- oder Biskuitteig entweder recht einfach oder mit aufwendigen Zutaten, also viel Butter, Mandeln, Zitrone oder Rosinen, bereitet und mit Schokolade überzogen oder auch mit Puderzucker bestäubt.“
> [image]

### On the joke

The joke is, that Google is supposed to collaborate with the food manufacturer Oetker on a *Googlehupf*-Project. It then continues in the same spirit, claiming that the dough particles would gather health related information about the user, even as the thing is bought. Basically, it's all about a massive conspiracy combining the unique assets of both giant companies.

Comment: I would accept this one, not mine.

Comment: Thank you, but I feel you did better on the phonological part.

Comment: Actually, all of the three answers are very good! Thanks! Ingmar answered within 2 minutes and clarified the issue for me. But Jan and Ludi expanded quite a bit on the original answer. I probably ultimately chose Jan's answer as the "Accepted Answer" due to his last sentence. I have been always wondering why taz.de composes these fable-styled narratives.

Comment: I like and upvoted his answer too, because from the question's phrasing it is not crucial to go into the etymology of Gugelhupf and his phonological part is crucial. On the other hand it makes sense to resolve the (likely) misunderstanding with "Hupf", so I didn't remove mine.

Comment: An additional note: The dessert also has a translation in English. It is called a `bundt cake`, at least the sponge based variants (Rührkuchen). The yeast variants cannot be translated without being misleading. But for the sponge ones, it is a really good translation, since 'bundt` is also defined by the shape, not content.

Comment: @rumtscho would you mind my adding that to the answer?

Comment: @Ludi I won't mind at all, I think the answer is a good place for that information. You are welcome to edit it in.

Comment: Well one might call it a conspiracy theory but I guess it actually has a very valid point. It's still better to be aware of such possibilities than to be blissfully unaware of them and think of Google as some kind of benign entity or something :) Tracking is indeed everywhere already.

Answer (score 4):

The Gugelhupf (or Guglhupf) is a very famous sort of cake in German-speaking regions.

DWDS defines it as follows:

> Gugelhupf -hopf m. südd. öst. schweiz. ‘runder Napf-, Königskuchen’, vergleichend zusammengesetzt aus Gugel, Kugel ‘enganliegende Männerkappe als Kapuze’, mhd. gugel(e), kugel, kogel, ahd. kugula (9. Jh.), einer Entlehnung von lat. cuculla ‘Hülle für den Kopf, Kapuze’, in Verbindung mit -hupf, -hopf, einer Variante von Hefe (s. d.).

So it is a cake that looks like a certain type of hat for men and contains yeast.

The play on word with "Googlehupf" is that "Google" and "Gugel" are pronounced the same in German, so a cake made by Google would of course be a Googlehupf.

---

So the real answer to your question without much explaination is:

*-hupf* is an old, alternative form of *Hefe* (*yeast*).

Comment: Confirmed by Kluge Entymologisches Wörterbuch.

Answer (score 2):

It's a play on words with the famous Austrian (?) dessert *[Gugelhupf](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gugelhupf)*.